# How to use one to many relations (hasMany and belongsto) in Ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new to Ember.js and i am trying to write a small page where we can post some small status and people can add various comments for it. The models are defined as follows along with data

```
Posts.Post= DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: 'post user'}),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async: true})
});
Posts.Post.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   title: 'Learn Ember.js',
   user: 'Post User 1',
   comments: [1,2]
 } 
];

Posts.Comment= DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: 'comment user'}),
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
});
Posts.Comment.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   post_id: 1,
   title: 'Learn Ember.js',
   user: 'Comment User 1'

 },
 {
   id: 2,
   post_id: 1,
   title: 'Post Item 2',
   user: 'Comment User 2'

 },
];
```

I am not sure of the route and controllers, i need to be able to update comments and posts based on updates from users.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch between `post` and `post_id`. The following will work:

Your post model:

```
Posts.Post= DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: 'post user' }),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', { async: true })
});

Posts.Post.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Learn Ember.js',
      user: 'Post User 1',
      comments: [1,2]
    } 
  ],
});
```

Your comment model:

```
Posts.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: 'comment user' }),
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
});

Posts.Comment.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES = [
    {
      id: 1,
      post: 1,
      title: 'Learn Ember.js',
      user: 'Comment User 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      post: 1,
      title: 'Post Item 2',
      user: 'Comment User 2'
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to use title instead of id.